# Groovy DateTime Format unexpected output

Tags: datetime, groovy

The below code doesn't return the expected output. What's wrong with it?

```
def a = new Test(new Date());

println a.getLogFormatDate()

class Test
{
    String _dateTime;
    static final String _logDateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    static final String _timeZoneUTC = "UTC";

    Test(Date dateTime)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getLogFormatDate()
     {
        return _dateTime.format(_logDateFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone(_timeZoneUTC));
     }
}​
```

**Expected Output:**

> Mon Nov 12 14:10:46 UTC 2018

**Actual Output:**

> E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `_dateTime` class field with type `String`, so your `getLogFormatDate` calls

```
String.format("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

while you expect

```
Date.format("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

to be called.

Define `_dateTime` field as `Date` and it will works as you expect.